# SCP command Clarification

Tags: linux, networking, unix, scp

I'm using the scp commands to pull some files from the remote server and one variation of the command is not working.

I have 2 files names one.xml and two.xml in a remote server and I'm pulling these two files into the current dir using the following command:

```
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/one.xml .
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/two.xml .
```

The above command works fine but if I use wildcards to pull all the xml files in a single shot as shown below it returns scp: No match.

```
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/*.xml .
```

Why is it working if I pull the files individually and not working if I try to pull using wildcards.

Comment: What shell are you using? Does it permit you to pass through wildcards to a command without escaping them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working -- your simple example works in my tests.

As a potential suggestion, your wildcards may have to be escaped in order to avoid being interpreted by your local shell, *before* they get passed to the remote shell.  So with your command, your local shell may be looking for files matching *.xml in your current working directory.  Try encapsulating the remote part of the command with single quotes, as:

```
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:'/student/class/Intermediate/*.xml' .
```